# Sphinx Search term boost

Tags: sphinx

Is there a way I can add a weight to each word in my query?

I need to do something like this (Lucene query):

> "word1^50|word2^45|word3^25|word4^20"

All answers I found online are old and I was hoping this changed.

**UPDATE:**

Sphinx introduced term boosting in version 2.2.3: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/extended-syntax.html

Usage:

```
select id,weight() from ljplain where match('open source^2') limit 2 option ranker=expr('sum(max_idf)*1000');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No nothing really changed. The same old workarounds should still work tho.